# Can't display UIImage in UIImageView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview

i want to display an UIImage within a UIImageView but it doesn't work and i don't know why.
could you please help me.

i am using the following coding:

```
 -(void) showCorrectedImage {

 MyAppDelegate *delegate = (MyAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
 CorrectedImageController *imageController = [[CorrectedImageController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CorrectedImageView" bundle:nil];
 UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];

 imageController.imageView = imgView;

 [imgView release];
 [delegate.navController pushViewController:imageController animated:YES];

}
```

There is a xib file called "CorrectedImageView.xib" and within the xib i have placed an UIImageView. I have connected the UIImageView outlet with the image view and the view outlet with the view.
original Image is defined as UIImage and initialized with a file.

br.,
martin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In these lines

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:originalImage];
imageController.imageView = imgView;
[imgView release];
```

you're creating a new UIImageView instance, when you already have one in the XIB file. If your connections in IB are good, this should be all you need to do:

```
imageController.imageView.image = originalImage;
```

Also, please don't forget to release imageController after you push it like this:

```
[imageController release];
```

P.S. As to why your code doesn't work, the newly created UIImageView instance, while it replaces the previous one in the view controller, it's not added as a subview of the view controller's view. So after your code executes, you have:

1. An UIImageView instance retained as a subview of the main view.
2. Another UIImageView instance initialized with your image and retained in the view controller, but not a subview of the main view, and therefore not displayed.

Comment: sorry, but i don't get it running. maybe my nib file is wrong.
it looks as follows:

-File's Owner (CorrectedImageController)
-First Responder (UIResponder)
-View (UIView)
--ImageView (UIImageView9

I've connected the File's Owner view property to the View Element
and the File's Owner imageView property to the ImageView Element.

Did i miss something ?

BR,
Martin

Answer (score 0):

sorry, but i don't get it running. maybe my nib file is wrong.
it looks as follows:

```
-File's Owner (CorrectedImageController)
-First Responder (UIResponder)
-View (UIView)
--ImageView (UIImageView9
```

I've connected the File's Owner view property to the View Element
and the File's Owner imageView property to the ImageView Element.

Did i miss something ?

BR,
Martin